# Select filter parou de funcionar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

Olá,

Pessoal preciso de um help, tenho um select filter que até ontem estava funcionando, alguém mexeu e parou de funcionar, como não entendo muito de jquery, resolvi perguntar aqui.

Obs: O arquivo jquery continua sendo chamado normalmente.

Quando o usuário seleciona todas as cidades, obviamente o sistema lista tudo, mas quando ele clica seleciona alguma, só é exibido o resultado da cidade filtrada, os demais results ficam ocultos.

Seção 1 - Filtro

```
<section id="citys">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Cidade</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="list_citys">
              <option value="all_city">Todas</option>
              <option value="city_sp">São Paulo</option>
              <option value="city_barueri">Barueri (Tamboré)</option>
              <option value="city_campinas">Campinas</option>
              <option value="city_guaruja">Guarujá</option>
              <option value="city_santos">Santos</option>
              <option value="city_santo_andre">Santo Andre</option>
              <option value="city_sao_campo">São Bernado do Campo</option>
              <option value="city_sao_jose_campos">São José dos Campos</option>
              <option value="city_ribeirao_preto">Ribeirão Preto</option>
              <option value="city_outlet">Outlet</option>
            </select>
            <br>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

SEÇÃO 2 - RESULTADO

```
<section class="list_citys_shop">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
          <li><h4 class="shop-text-h4">São Paulo - Centro</h4></li>
          <li class="new-citys" >Second item</li>
          <li class="new-citys">Third item</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
          <li><h4 class="shop-text-h4">São Paulo - Morumbi</h4></li>
          <li class="new-citys" >Second item</li>
          <li class="new-citys">Third item</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_barueri">
          <li><h4 class="shop-text-h4">Barueri - Centro</h4></li>
          <li class="new-citys" >Second item</li>
          <li class="new-citys">Third item</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_barueri">
          <li><h4 class="shop-text-h4">Barueri - Tropical</h4></li>
          <li class="new-citys" >Second item</li>
          <li class="new-citys">Third item</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
  </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select#list_citys').change(function() {
  var filter = $(this).val()
  filterList(filter);
});
function filterList(value) {
  var list = $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys");
  $(list).fadeOut("fast");
  if (value == "all_city") {
    $(".list-citys").find("ul").each(function (i) {
      $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
    });
  } else {
    $(".list_citys_shop").find("ul[data-category*=" + value + "]").each(function (i) {
      $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro na consola?

Comment: Estás a usar ID no seletor, mas o select não tem ID, tem `name`. Devia ser `$('select[name="list_citys"]')` ---> https://jsfiddle.net/r3f9t9jo/

Comment: Ok, comenta aqui ou clica em [edit] na pergunta

Comment: Funcionou Sergio, mas ainda tenho um problema. Quando seleciono uma cidade, todas as informações desaparecem, inclusive a que era para estar visível. Não mostra nenhum erro no console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens os seletores meio misturados.

Estás a usar ID no seletor, mas o select não tem ID, tem `name`. Devia ser `$('select[name="list_citys"]')`.

Para além disso `$(".list-citys").find("ul")` não faz sentido porque `ul` é o elemento que tem a classe `.list-citys`, e não descendente como o `.find()` precisa para encontrar.

Uma versão a funcionar podia ser assim:

```
$('select[name="list_citys"]').change(filterList);

function filterList(e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    if (value == "all_city") $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideDown();
    else $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideUp();
    $(".list_citys_shop ul[data-category*=" + value + "] .new-citys").stop().slideDown();
}
```

**Exemplo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggd4fzgL/1/)**

Comment: Problema resolvido. Muito obrigado Serigo, me ajudou muito.

Comment: @Leonardo ótimo, tirei o  `fadeOut("fast");` porque nunca tinhas `fadeIn` e fi só com `slideUp` e `slideDown`.

Comment: Ficou mais bonito mesmo. Muito obrigado.